# Only want to pull JSON Class not all data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, yql

Trying to only pull text from a class with a unique name using `$.getJSON` and YQL.  Right now it pulls all data and strips out tags.  Anyone know if this can be achieved?

```
  function filterData(data){
    // filter all the nasties out
    // no body tags
    data = data.replace(/<?\/body[^>]*>/g,'');
    // no linebreaks
    data = data.replace(/[\r|\n]+/g,'');
    // no comments
    data = data.replace(/<--[\S\s]*?-->/g,'');
    // no noscript blocks
    data = data.replace(/<noscript[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/noscript>/g,'');
    // no script blocks
    data = data.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/script>/g,'');
    // no self closing scripts
    data = data.replace(/<script.*\/>/,'');

    // the below doesn't work of course, but if I could use jQuery I would do as follows:
    data = $(data).find('.count').text();
    return data;
  }
```

Here is part of the JSON it pulls:

```
"div": [
             {
              "id": "store-page-rating",
              "div": [
               {
                "id": "store-six-month-rating",
                "div": {
                 "style": "float:left;",
                 "span": {
                  "class": "rating",
                  "img": {
                   "alt": "Rating 8.68/10",
                   "class": "stars fourhalf",
                   "src": "http://images4.resellerratings.com/CDN-1328669559/static/images/blankstar.gif",
                   "style": "width: 80px; height: 16px;",
                   "title": "Rating 8.68/10"
                  },
                  "span": [
                   {
                    "class": "count",
                    "content": "27"
                   },
```

How can I just display the "27" on class "count" instead of ALL the data on the domain?

Comment: If you want to pull only 1 class (the one which has 27),

div[0].div[0].div.span.span[0].content will return 27

Comment: How/where are you using YQL, and to do what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do and was unaware of was to use XPATH at the end of the YQL statement.

```
    select content from html where url="http://www.resellerratings.com/store/Burkett_Restaurant_Equipment_Supplies"
 and xpath="//span[@class='count']"
```

[See here](http://y.ahoo.it/D59bj)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have much of a choice here, `yql` provides you a proxy to query the resources that are **not on your domain**. you can make your own server side proxy that can filter the results and return you the desired output in `json` format.